# Oracle 11g XE installation problems on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, oracle

I follow this  link [link](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/) to install Oracle 11g XE on Ubuntu 14.04.After Following all the steps, still it is showing following problems:

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus.
```

whenever i try to open oracle on web browser, oracle remain unable to install.

```
http://localhost:8081/apex/f?p=4950
```

BTW I have also XAMPP installed in my pc.

updates: after is installation i did this, But still oracle Not works.

```
usr@pc: cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 01-JAN-2016 13:03:31

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/usr-pc/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=usr_pc)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                01-JAN-2016 13:03:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/usr-pc/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=usr-pc)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ echo $http_proxy
localhost
```

Latest Updates:

```
 usr@pc:himadree@himadree-Inspiron-1545:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ export http_proxy=http://localhost
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ echo $http_proxy
http://localhost
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ sqlplusError 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible
```

with unset proxy But still same error:

```
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ unset http_proxy
usr@pc:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ echo $http_proxy

usr@pc::/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible
```

[Error  image http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TXqw.png)

it is already  been 9 times failed attempt to install oracle 11g.I am mentally exhausted.
please suggest me,how can i fix it.please let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks :)

Comment: It appears your listener is starting so you are actually really close. I believe http_proxy needs the http:// so the for mat to: http:// localhost / or just unset it entirely (it is not required). See if that makes any different.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an off topic question and really more of a question for the Oracle Community but there are a few things you need to check. First, make sure you set all the environmental variables correctly (such as ORACLE_HOME) something like one of these should show you the path that is currently set but make sure it is correct by doing an ls on whatever the path is shown:

```
$ /usr/bin/env |grep ORACLE
or use:
$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

Next, you can try to manually start the listener and replace [listenername] with your listenername store in listener.ora (found under $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/ usually):

```
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin/lsnrctl start [listenername]
```

Note: the default path is /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin/lsnrctl, however yours may be different since your path above is looking for /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin

If you can get the listener started then try to connect using sqlplus:

```
$ sqlplus
SQL> CONNECT SYS as SYSDBA
```

I'm guessing if the installation completed without error (you can check the logs) that it's probably just ORACLE_HOME is set wrong but the logs will reveal the kind of specific error messages that will really help you trouble shoot this. Hope this all helps.

Comment: Thanks @snorp   i got error on this    /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin$ sqlplus
Error 46 initializing SQL*Plus
HTTP proxy setting has incorrect value
SP2-1502: The HTTP proxy server specified by http_proxy is not accessible

Comment: Did the listener start okay? That's probably the bigger issue. Do you have http_proxy set? (echo $http_proxy) it shouldn't need to be unless you're using a proxy so maybe do an ( unset http_proxy  OR set it to localhost: export http_proxy=http://localhost )

Comment: Thank @snorp for your reply. I followed your suggestion and updated  my post above.still i am facing some error.Thanks

Comment: I just realized that it formatted my comment wrong, I posted above but basically the http_proxy needs the http:// then the hostname:port. You also could just unset it.

Comment: Thank you  @snorp for your continuous reply.I am following your comments.I have add latest updates on my post.Please can you check it.Thanks.BTW i want to say, xampp is on localhost.do you think it can be problem.Thank you so much.

Comment: No that should be unrelated. However I saw in your update your have http_proxy set to `http://localhost:8080` try just `http://localhost` and if that still won't connect try an `unset http_proxy` (my test env has no proxy set).

Comment: Thank you @snorp for your reply.But Same error  with proxy and without proxy.please check my post updates.

Comment: Run a `sudo netstat -nlp |grep 8080` and see you should get something like:  `tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      11403/tnslsnr` The key thing is that tnslsnr is at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you @snorp for your reply. I did sudo netstat -nlp |grep 8080, but nothing is displayed for both   lsnrctl start and
 lsnrctl stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33763/discussion-between-snorp-and-user5005768).

Comment: Thank you @snorp. if you still get some times then please let inform at which PDT times you usually spend on askubuntu.so that we can coordinate our free times.Thank you

Comment: Hey, you can acutally basically post comments in chat so we don't need to be online at the same time. That being said I'm usually around between 6am and 2pm your time (PDT)